# Function overloading with different return types

Tags: c++, function, c++11, overloading

I know we are not allowed to overload functions based on return type only. Suppose I have two functions `double convert(string num)` and `int convert(string num)`
Consider the following sample code :

```
double convert(string num){
    stringstream ss;
    double d_num;
    ss<<num;
    ss>>d_num;
    return d_num;
}

int convert(string num){
    int i_num;
    /*.....
   same as previous
   .....
   */
   return i_num;
}
```

And in the main() :

```
int main(){
    string st="09122321";
    double d1=convert(st);
    int i1=convert(st);

}
```

Although I overloaded the function differring only in return type but as I am assigning them to data types based on their return type wasn't I supposed to get the converted `string num` in `double d1` and `int i1`  ?

Now I get the error similar to:

> error: new declaration 'int convert(std::string)'|  error: ambiguates
>   old declaration 'double convert(std::string)'|

How will I make the `convert()` work if I want it to have it different return types by overloading the function ?

Comment: Just rename it. Have `to_int(std::string)` and `to_float(std::string)`.

Comment: There's an old trick to say `struct convert { convert(string); operator double(); operator int(); };`

Comment: FYI STL has already functions for these conversions namely [`std::stoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) and [`std::stod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How will I make the convert() work if I want it to have it different return types by overloading the function ?

You can create a simple function template.

```
template <typename T>
T convert(std::string const& num){
    std::istringstream ss(num);
    T d_num;
    ss>>d_num;
    return d_num;
}
```

and specialize it for `std::string` so that the input argument is used to copy construct the returned `std::string`.

```
template <>
std::string convert<std::string>(std::string const& in){
    return in;
}
```

and use it as:

```
auto d1 = convert<double>(st);
auto i1 = convert<int>(st);
```

Comment: For brownie points specialize the template to simply return the string when the target type is a string!

Comment: Only remaining suggestion - pass by const reference, and maybe return by it too in specialized case (debatable).

Comment: @NeilKirk, the return type has to remain `std::string` if the return type of the function template is `T`. Otherwise, it wouldn't count as a specialization.

Comment: Cool I didn't know that.

Comment: Any additional info or links to `template` will be helpful

Comment: There are plenty of resources on the web if you search for "C++ template". You can start from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to pass the required return type as an output variable. With this, your code would become:

```
void convert(string num, double *d_num){
    stringstream ss;
    ss<<num;
    ss>>*d_num;
}

void convert(string num, int *i_num){
    /*.....
   same as previous
   .....
   */
}
```

Since the functions differ in their argument-signature, the overload is fine.

Comment: It'll be a valid overloading since the functions differ in argument types but I was expecting functions differing only by return type

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overload based upon return type in C and C++, but you can cheat by returning a class and providing *conversion operators*. (And don't forget an insertion operator.) Behold:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct fib
{
  unsigned long value;

  fib( unsigned n )
  {
    value = !!n;
    if (!n) return;
    unsigned long prev = 0;
    while (--n)
    {
      long next = value + prev;
      prev = value;
      value = next;
    }
  }

  operator long () const { return value; }
  operator std::string () const { return std::to_string( value ); }
};

std::ostream& operator << ( std::ostream& outs, const fib& f )
{
  return outs << (std::string)f;
}

void print( double x )
{
  std::cout << "fib 3 = " << x << "\n";
}

int main()
{
  long        x = fib( 5 );
  std::string s = fib( 7 );

  print( fib( 3 ) );
  std::cout << "fib 5 = " << x << "\n";
  std::cout << "fib 7 = " << s << "\n";
  std::cout << "fib 9 = " << fib( 9 ) << "\n";
}
```

Enjoy!